# why does python function not work with particular values entered

Tags: python

```
a = int(input("in a: "))
b = int(input("in b: "))
c = int(input("in c: "))

def test(a, b, c):
    if a == b:
        a = 0
        b = 0

    if a == c:
        a = 0
        c = 0

    if b == c:
        b = 0
        c = 0

    if a == b == c:
        a = 0
        b = 0
        c = 0
    
    print(f"The sum is {a+b+c}")

    return a, b, c
    
test(a, b, c)
```

It works except for when I input the same 3 values it doesn't return 0. The intended program is so that every time an identical number is entered the sum will be 0.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: You change a and b to 0 and then c stays 3.

Comment: Run the code in your head: when you call the function with 3, 3, 3, the first `if` is correct. Now both `a` and `b` are re-assigned to 0. Now the second `if` is not correct because `0 != 3`...

Comment: hey guys thanks for the help, ive updated the code to make it more clear

Comment: That does not change anything, my first comment stays true word for word.

Comment: simply use `print()` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed. It is called `"prind debuging"` and it helps to see what code is doing. And you will see that it changes values in `a,b`  before you check `a == b == c` and it doesn't match. You may have to use `a == b == c` as first expression

Comment: thanks, i was unaware of the importance at the order of which the code is placed in for python. very helpful!

Comment: The order of the code is important for **every** programming language. Would you expect that the code executes in some random order?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have used many if conditions, the value of `a` and `b` changes to 0 in the first `if` condition while `c` remains 3, and `a==b==c` condition is no more valid. hence sum is 0+0+3 = 3.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the logic clearer. Stacking multiple if statements can lead to undesired results like this. What happening here is that the first if statement will turn `a` and `b` to `0` which makes your final if statement to evaluate `false` even if initially `a = b = c`. This can be easily fixed using else-if statements.

```
def test(a, b, c):
    if a == b == c:
      a = b = c = 0
      
    elif a == b:
      a = b = 0

    elif b == c:
      b = c = 0
    
    elif a == c:
      a = c = 0

    print(f"The sum is {a + b + c}")

    return a, b, c
```